# appending to autoComplete

Tags: primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0, PF M3 and GF 3.1.

I have a autocomplete control in my email form. As soon as I select from the drop down suggestions provided by autocomplete control, it replaces the old value in the control. How can I make it work so that each time a new selection is made the selected text is appended to the previously selected text.

My view file is :

```
<p:autoComplete id="emailForm"
value="#{mail.emailTo}"
required="true"
completeMethod="#{myController.complete}"
var="p"
itemLabel="#{p.lastName} &lt;#{p.email}&gt;"
itemValue="#{p}"
size="60">
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{myController.handleSelect}"/> 
</p:autoComplete>
```

All the help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean exactly by `selected text is appended to the previously selected text`?

If I understand correctly, this is not a good practice: means that your `complete method` (`myController.complete`) has a wrong implementation. You could revise your code...

Anyway, you could append the entered keys(text) with the one selected as a suggestion by appending the value `mail.emailTo` with the result returned from DB, handled by `myController.complete` method.

**Update**:

Firstly you should consider upgrade to RC1, and then read the manual ( http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html ), so you can understand the differences between [simple autocomplete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf) and [autocomplete with pojo support](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf);

You will use pojo support when working with your own objects(and not just lists), also you will use itemLabel and itemValue in the same case. When working with pojo you get the converting error because you have to implement your own converter. If all these things are strange to you, then use the simple autocomplete and you'll be fine!

Consider reading all those links I've provided to you for a better understanding of Primefaces components in general (autocomplete in particular)

Comment: Thanks Spauny for answering my Q.

Comment: @user1097366 Thank me after your problem is solved and you have accepted your answer... :)

Comment: Thanks Spauny for answering my Q. I am a little confused with p:autocomplete feature of PF. Should the value field point to the field which will have all the selected text from autocomplete(in my case it will be  String), Does itemLabel and itemValue have  any dependency on value field. Because if I make the value field as String, it gives an exception saying that value field (which is of type String) does not have property of lastName and email. CAn you please explain with a example. Thanks so much for your help which always comes very quickly.

Comment: I did implement the converter for autoComplete.    What I want to achieve is similar to the "To" field of outlook or gmail (new mail message). User types a name and selects it from dropdown which then gets appended to the previous text. In my case it works but the help which comes after I type a name replaces the old text.

Comment: @user1097366 Firstly you should not use `p:ajax` inside `autocomplete`, because autocomplete component already provides ajax support... Also it would be nice if you upload some images to a image host(and then edit your question by providing these images) so I can see exactly the problem

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to move it to chat. Is it possible for me to email you the image of my problem.  Alternatively, I just want to implement TO (compose email) of gmail/outlook where I type a name and suggestion comes. As soon as I select one, it gets appended to older selections. Thanks a ton for your time and help.

Comment: @user1097366 you do not have to move it to chat... Also I can't access personal e-mail from work (where I am now), but you can upload your images here: http://imageshack.us/ and then give me the links

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/testhzi.jpg/ Here it shows how I want it to implement. User will type a name and it email will be suggested by autocomplete. User selects the email (which appears in autocomplete field), select second name and this email gets appended to the first email.

Comment: @user1097366 I don't think it gets appended - I see two e-mails separated by a comma(the name surrounded by "" and e-mail by <>), and then you write `t` and in the results you get happens to be the previous e-mail because it contains `t` key, actually all the autocomplete emails provided are containing `t`... So you should change you method implementation to take only the names that starts with `t`, if want that way

Comment: I am not referring to the drop down values. I want the To field to have all the emails which I have selected. Please note that first email does not contain "t" in it.

Comment: @user1097366 I'm talking about the e-mails provided in the dropdown - all have a `t` inside... And I still don't understand you problem: I see that you have more emails there, so the current selection doesn't replace the old one, also you can choose a single email at a time by typing the name...

Comment: Let me rephrase my question - With reference to the image, user first types letter "D" (gets a list of emails containing D in the drop down, selects one of them say for ex d@d.com and this appears in the input field), user then types "t" (gets a list of emails containing t in the drop down, selects t@t.com and input field now contains d@d.com, t@t.com). My problem is my input field first contains d@d.com and as soon as I select t@t.com, input field becomes t@t.com whereas I want both emails in it. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1097366 Than the image provided does not reflect your application? because there, the emails are appended, separated with comma... Anyway I see where the problem is now, but using simple autocomplete won't resolve your problem, you have think of a better solution, involving maybe javascript/jquery; the closest you can get with autocomplete is by adding in a list every selected email, and then append all the emails from the list with the new result showed in page.

Comment: Thanks Spauny for your time. I have it already implemented it as a new field showing all the appended results. I will try with JS. Thanks again.